# python accessing returned variable

Tags: python, caffe, pycaffe

I'm still not comfortable with python. Experimenting with a deep learning open source code, I'm writting a test code and I can see it runs like below. (using datasets package and pascal_voc module in it, BTW, this is from py-faster-rcnn code)

```
>>> import datasets
>>> import datasets.pascal_voc as pv

>>> d = datasets.pascal_voc('trainval', '2007')
>>> d._load_pascal_annotation('{0:06d}'.format(5))
Removed 2 difficult objects
{'boxes': array([[262, 210, 323, 338],
       [164, 263, 252, 371],
       [240, 193, 294, 298]], dtype=uint16), 'flipped': False, 'gt_classes': array([9, 9, 9], dtype=int32), 'gt_overlaps': <3x21 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float32'>'
```

the function `_load_pascal_annotation` returns values as shown below.

```
def _load_pascal_annotation(self, index):
....
    return {'boxes' : boxes,
        'gt_classes': gt_classes,
        'gt_overlaps' : overlaps,
        'flipped' : False}
```

I want to extract the array of the 'boxes' from the returned dictionary and use it to draw something. I tried `d['boxes']` but give me error below.

```
>>> d['boxes']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'pascal_voc' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

How can I extract the coordinate values from returned value of  _load_pascal_annotation?

Comment: `>>d._load_pascal_annotation('{0:06d}'.format(5))['boxes']`  try this and let me know

Comment: @MarlonAbeykoon, that works too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your library at all, but from what you've shown, you probably want to assign the results of `_load_pascal_annotation` to a new variable, then access the `boxes` item in the dictionary. Try something like this:

```
data = d._load_pascal_annotation('{0:06d}'.format(5))
print(data['boxes'])
```

One thing I'd note however is that methods with a single leading underscore in their names are generally intended to be private (e.g. they're not part of the class's public API). There may be some other method or attribute on your `d` object that you should be using instead which will call `_load_pascal_annotation` in the background (and do something appropriate with its return value).

Answer (score 2):

You call the `_load_pascal_annotation` method but you don't keep a reference to its return value.

Try:

```
r_value = d._load_pascal_annotation('{0:06d}'.format(5))
r_value['boxes']
```

Comment: oh, I feel like a fool now. Thanks!